# Bean injection in groovy class

Tags: java, spring, groovy

Currently i am rewriting a java project by groovy, then i came across this problem

Java:

```
public abstract class AbstractJavaClass {
  private ConfigClass configClass;
  public void go();  
  g/setter
}

public class JavaClass extends AbstractJavaClass {
  @Override
  public void go() {
    do something;
  }
}
```

the ConfigClass member was injected in xml ways

```
<bean id = 'configClass' class='ConfigClass'></bean>

<bean id = 'javaClass' class='JavaClass'>
 <property name='configClass' ref='configClass'/>
</bean>
```

Groovy：

```
class GroovyClass extends AbstractJavaClass {
  @Override
  public void go() {
    do something;
  }
}
```

How should i implement the property ref in groovy class?

At last i used this method.

Groovy：

```
class GroovyClass extends AbstractJavaClass {

  public GroovyClass() {
    configClass = new ConfigClass();
    configClass.setSomeAttributes();
  }

  @Override
  public void go() {
    do something;
  }
}
```

Comment: Refer this Link : http://www.jroller.com/pyrasun/category/Groovy

Comment: the groovy class should behave like the java one.  if you have an error/exception/... please add it to the question.

Comment: @VaibhavJain thanks,i am reading it

Comment: @cfrick sorry i can't quite catch u, i tried something like #Resource Class instance in groovy class, but it would not overwrite the member in abstractClass

Comment: @VaibhavJain , I have read through it , u mean i could declare it as private ConfigClass configClass? I tried ,but when goes in the go function in debug, there exists two configClass variables and one of them is null.